# Mandrill_Unknown_Sender error when searching for email

Tags: mandrill

Getting `Mandrill_Unknown_Sender` exception when searching recently sent messages.

Here are arguments that are passed to [searchTimeSeries funciton](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html#method=search-time-series).  For this example, I'm using a dummy email address, but I get same error when I use a valid email address.

**update:** Mandrill support says that it's a bug on their end. For now, a workaround will be not to pass in the `senders` parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error happens due to invalid sender , in this case support@mywebsite.com . Did you send any emails from this Sender ? I saw that you put an dummy email address in query, but wanted to check if you were sending the a right address in the "senders" .

I was able to reproduce the  error that you got, when I entered a wrong email address in senders input, and I got the following response:

```
{
"status": "error",
"code": 2,
"name": "Unknown_Sender",
"message": "No such sender \"You provided one or more Sender addresses that don't exist: abs@abs.com"
```

}

but when I corrected the "senders" input , the problem went away.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I've sent an email to Mandrill asking them. I got a reply.  They said that it's a bug on their end.